# How to Determine Correct Color Space for Bitmaps in Android?

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, color-space, android-color

I'm working on an Android app and need to optimize bitmap loading based on the device's screen color space. My questions are:

- How can I find out the color space used by the device's screen?
- Does the app's rendering color space always match the device's screen color space?
- For bitmap loading in BitmapFactory, how do I choose the right color space for the inPreferredColorSpace property?

Please note that my app is rendered on an `OpenGL surface`. Do I need also to configure the openGL surface to match the device's screen colorspace ?

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the term device's screen color space is applicable here(at least for Android). One screen(both physical and logical) can use different color spaces since all the color spaces represent the same colors and can be indistinguishable from one another with a proper device-specific approach. I guess you are talking about the apparatus(GPU, engine, renderer) that supports specific color spaces better than another.

The rendering of the colorspaces may differ from renderer to renderer because some renderers work better with certain color spaces than with others and vice-versa - usually, it is due to the specifics of the actual implementation.

As you've specified you are using OpenGL rather than Vulkan(which is color space agnostic - since it has optimized rendering pretty much any color space and is not supported by old machines) - for OpenGL, the most natural and proficient color space is sRGB(of course, if the GPU can perform the correct conversion - if it cannot - the color space won't matter - because in the end all of them will be converted to the GPUs default one which is typically linear if I remember correctly) and if you have all the bitmap resources as sRGB (or at least can convert to it) - use it.

For older devices with low-quality old GPUs - the answer would be linear which is more natural but heavier.

For Vulcan supporting devices - use whatever suits you best in any given situation.

OpenGL can also use YUV(which should be more performant, etc.), but it is not natively supported by it - so to be rendered on the screen, the YUV file will be converted to RGB...

In all cases, some gamma correction may be needed afterward depending on the device it is used at - that is why this option is present in most of the games - this value is not uniform for all the different screens and GPUs and their combination.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So i do not understand the purpose of color management :( we say that if an image is in P3 color space, then not all screens can render all colors in the images and that mean that the image must be converted to sRGB color space to be show correctly. if knowing the screen color space is irrelevant so how to know when i must convert my bitmap in srgb or use it P3 because the device can show it ?

Comment: Because it is determined not by the screen color space but by the renderer and the GPU settings - most of them behave similarly on Android. The screens, on the other hand, are very hard to adjust programmatically because there are plenty of those - we should rely on the OpenGl and GPU settings - rely on the vendor to set it up correctly. If you want to give your user fine-tuning abilities - let them adjust gamma, brightness, or whatever. Fine-tuning the color space in code is indeed close to pointless for Android - it is usually done for performance reasons rather than for color range reasons.

Comment: In this way what colorspace in bitmapfactory to choose when I load the bitmap ? I think i miss something :(

Comment: @zeus apparently. The `BitmapFactory` gives you colorspace of the selected resource. Load you image via `Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.image_resource);' or `Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageInputStream)` and then pull its color space like `ColorSpace cs = image.getColorSpace();` it will give you an enum value from [`ColorSpace.Named`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorSpace.Named).

Comment: @zeus After than you can convert pixel-by-pixel to other color space using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils.html)

Comment: It is pointless, though - it won't differ too much on the screen, and it is always better to have a resource already ready with the needed color space and then just use it.

Comment: that not what android suggest to do :( https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/wide-color-photos-are-coming-to-android.html then say a bad practice is to Upload image as texture without necessary conversion. In API 26, we added inPreferredColorSpace in BitmapFactory.Option, which allows you to specify the target color space you want the decoded bitmap to have. and the question is with value to set in this inPreferredColorSpace ?

Comment: @zeus - my answer is unchanged - the most performant one for OpenGL on Android is sRGB, and having resources preformatted in that color space is the best option. I have never used the `inPreferredColorSpace,` but I assume it does what you would do manually but it converts automatically. It should cause a slight performance drawback, but with modern chips, I'm sure you can neglect it(of course, if the texture doesn't weigh 2gb or something))). So generally use preformatted images in sRGB -if it is not possible, in case you have drawing issues - decode them to sRGB. If no issues - don't bother.

Comment: And regarding the bad practice - I think what they mean is when you rely on all the images to be sRGB without checking - you can't be sure 100% due to human error(designer flaw, image converting during sending, etc.); that is why they suggest converting every time. At least I think so. I would rather write a prebuild script that checks if the images are of sRGB than convert every image - it gives you more control, IMO.